# Does anyone have a working spring3 securty config using oauth2?

Tags: oauth, spring-security

I am trying to make spring security with oauth2 work but there is really no good tutorial out there. The tonr and sparkl example apps magically work but I won't have a spring client which maybe does some magic. So does anyone have a valid spring3 oauth2 config and/or tutorial plus the client config?

Thanx!

Comment: For which side of the equation?  The producer/server or the consumer/client?  What "magic" do you want clarification on from the Sparklr/Tonr examples?

Comment: I am looking for the server part. And the client is in this case an Android app, but that should not matter. I'd also like to see how easily I can create a server-side list of granted auths (whcih clients a user granted access) with possibility to revoke access.